# How does the lottery work?

Tags: suikoden-3

In Suikoden 3, there is a lottery you can enter to win extra cash. You buy tickets and then later return and check if they won. When you can buy them and when you can check them is based on game time, with a new lottery drawing happening every so often. My question is this:

How often is that every so often? What is the actual timing on the lottery in Suikoden 3?

In addition to that, when the lottery does roll over to the next drawing period, do you have to leave the area and come back before you'll be able to check the winning numbers, or can you just check the sign again and it'll say the winning numbers for the one you entered, even if you haven't left the screen since buying the tickets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember trying this out before when I still had my PS2 and it seemed to always be about an hour.

Checked around and experience seems to be the [same w/ others](http://www.suikosource.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=14425)